# mySQL query Where issue

Tags: sql, mysql

Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong here?

```
$query = "SELECT * 
            FROM routes 
           WHERE econ <> maxecon 
        ORDER BY `id`;";
```

Without the `WHERE`, it works fine so I know that's the problem.

I want to select data where the column `econ` is NOT equal to `maxecon`. Is this even possible at this stage or do I have to take it all and chop it out in a loop?

Comment: assuming econ and maxecon are columns what are their datatypes?

Comment: What is the error message? Does the table have `econ` and `maxecon` columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does replacing <> with != work?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM routes WHERE econ != maxecon ORDER BY `id`";
```

Also, you don't need to include the ending semi-colon in your sql statement.

Comment: Odd how that works i mean i know it should its just "<>" should still hold true.

Answer (score 1):

What you've posted looks ok.  Have you definitely got examples where the two values are different? ( look at the results of your query without the WHERE ).

Also, are the fields nullable?  Been a long time since I've used MySQL, but on SQL Server, items are not comparable with the <> operator if one of the operands is NULL.

Try :-

```
SELECT * FROM routes 
WHERE 
   ( econ <> maxecon ) 
OR ( econ IS NULL AND maxecon IS NOT NULL )
OR ( econ IS NOT NULL AND maxecon IS NULL )
ORDER BY id;
```

Quoted for your implementation language, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM routes WHERE econ != maxecon ORDER BY `id`";
```

Of course, if econ is equal to maxecon then you will get no results, maybe you could post some sample data from the table?

Comment: In MySQL, <> and != are equivalent.  You should prefer the usage of <> since that is what SQL-92 dictates is the only valid not equals operator.

Answer (score 0):

I would try `!=` instead of `<>`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems:

- You may possibly need to backquote the names econ and maxecon.
- You may not have any data that meets the critieria.
- You may have data that meets the critieria, but only in cases where one column is NULL, and these won't be found by <>.

If the your problem is the last one, try NOT <=>, which is the negation of a special "NULL safe equals" operator in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

What programming language is this? Most I've used don't make you put a semicolon in the query itself...